# How to remove a class that has a child with a specific class name

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome-extension, typeerror

I am working on a google chrome extension for Facebook and I am having issues removing album, sponsored and suggested for you posts. I am trying to find out if a post is one of the three, then deleting the post. I keep getting this error: VM8866:7 Uncaught TypeError: posts.contains is not a function, on this section

```
if (posts.contains(album)){
```

For some reason all three if statements don't work

```
function removePosts (){

    var posts = document.querySelectorAll('._5jmm _5pat _3lb4 q_5hej__686'); // Facebook post classname
    var album = document.querySelectorAll('._1s31 u_5hej__xe4 t_5hej__xe2'); //album class
    var sponsored = document.querySelectorAll('._5pcp _5lel _2jyu _232_'); //select all sponsored class 
    var suggested = document.querySelectorAll('.Suggested for you'); //suggested for you class

    //removing album posts
    if (posts.contains(album)){
        while(posts.length > 0){
            posts[0].parentNode.removeChild(posts[0]);
        }
    } 

    //removing sponsored posts
    if (posts.contains(sponsored)){
        while(posts.length > 0){
            posts[0].parentNode.removeChild(posts[0]);
        }
    } 

    //removing suggested for you posts
    if (posts.contains(suggested)){
        while(posts.length > 0){
            posts[0].parentNode.removeChild(posts[0]);
        }
    } 
}
```

All help is appreciated

Comment: querySelectorAll returns an array-like collection, not an element, so it doesn't have contains() function. You probably need to use querySelector.

Comment: I've changed but but am now getting a: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contains' of null for if (posts.contains(album)). I reloaded the page and posts with the albums are still showing up along with sponsored posts.

Comment: It means your selector didn't match anything when this code ran. Facebook is rendering its page in JavaScript so you need to use MutationObserver or setTimeout or setInterval to detect the moment an element appears.

Comment: be aware that those classnames are random and may change once in a while.